# Fast integer ABS function

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

```
int X = a-b;
int d = Math.Abs(X);
```

I am pretty sure that .NET doesn't do inlining.  So, will I do if(), or is there some other less-known trick?

Comment: The .NET framework does do inlining. There is even a way to prevent it on a method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx

Comment: btw, I didn't mention, my X is in range 0-255, so for extra kick, I could probably use lookup for that, wasting only 510 bytes, or if I want to be proper, 510x4 (table of ints).  on the sidenote, is there stackexchange site for 'please optimize this few lines of code' unless it's codereview.se.com?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The JIT performs inlining in some circumstances. I don't know whether it inlines `Math.Abs` or not... but have you verified that this is actually a performance problem for you? Don't micro-optimize until you know that you need to, and then measure the performance gain from something like:

```
int d = X > 0 ? X : -X;
```

to verify that it's really worth it.

As noted by Anthony, the above won't (normally) work for `int.MinValue`, as `-int.MinValue == int.MinValue`, whereas `Math.Abs` will throw an `OverflowException`. You can force this in the straight C# as well using checked arithmetic:

```
int d = X > 0 ? X : checked(-X);
```

Comment: Those meddling minimum values!

Comment: `checked(-X)` - nice. didn't think of that.

Comment: I'd be extremely surprised if the .NET JIT wouldn't inline such Math Methods - at least the Hotspot JVM should do it and I think they'd be at least somewhat similar in that regard.

Comment: @Voo: Yes, I'd expect so too. I never like to make definite claims about such things without checking them though :)

Comment: On my computer the first expression above is 8 times faster than `Math.Abs` when I loop over all integer values in the range `[Int32.MinValue + 1, Int32.MaxValue - 1]`. When I apply `checked` on `-x`, the speedup for the complete loop (negative _and_ positive values) reduces to only 4 times faster. It of course dependent on how general the replacement `Abs` function need to be, but given that `checked` adds quite a lot of overhead for securing consistent handling of `Int32.MinValue` only, it is probably worthwhile to discard `checked` in most scenarios.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: It depends - would you rather have fast but dangerous code which can silently give you an unexpected value, or slightly slower but safer code? How often is `Math.Abs` really a bottleneck anyway?

Comment: @JonSkeet I appreciated your answer to this question very much, and in for example a general purpose library I definitely agree that safety is better than optimal speed. On the other hand, in a more isolated scenario where you are quite sure that you will never encounter values close to `Int32.MinValue`, leaving out `checked` could obviously buy you a little time. But of course you are right, `Math.Abs` is seldom a bottleneck. I just thought it was interesting to share that the `?=` expression could be so much faster than the built-in `Math.Abs` method.

Comment: In my machine (.Net 4.5 - Release) Math.Abs is slightly faster

Comment: just tested. checked and and non checked equal. they are faster than math.abs

Answer (score 28):

I did some performance tests, to find out whether you can actually save time using something besides the standard Math.Abs.

The results after executing all of these 2000000000 times (with `i` from -1000000000 to +1000000000, so without overflows):

```
Math.Abs(i)                    5839 ms     Factor 1
i > 0 ? i : -i                 6395 ms     Factor 1.09
(i + (i >> 31)) ^ (i >> 31)    5053 ms     Factor 0.86
```

(These numbers vary a bit for different runs)

Basically you can get a very slight improvement over `Math.Abs`, but nothing spectacular.

With the bit hack you can shave of a little of the time required for Math.Abs, but readability suffers severely.
With the simple branch you can actually be slower. Overall not worth it in my opinion.

All tests where run on a 32 bit OS, Net 4.0, VS 2010, Release mode, no debugger attached.

Here is the actual code:

```
class Program
{
    public static int x; // public static field. 
                         // this way the JITer will not assume that it is  
                         // never used and optimize the wholeloop away
    static void Main()
    {
        // warm up
        for (int i = -1000000000; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            x = Math.Abs(i);
        }

        // start measuring
        Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = -1000000000; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            x = Math.Abs(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        // warm up
        for (int i = -1000000000; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            x = i > 0 ? i : -i;
        }

        // start measuring
        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = -1000000000; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            x = i > 0 ? i : -i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        // warm up
        for (int i = -1000000000; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            x = (i + (i >> 31)) ^ (i >> 31);
        }

        // start measuring
        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        for (int i = -1000000000; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            x = (i + (i >> 31)) ^ (i >> 31);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: upvote for actually performing the benchmark and providing relevant benchmark environment details

Comment: i just tested and results are like below .net 4.5.2 32 bit : 5224
3759
3782

Comment: at x64 : 5764
4191
4026

Comment: my results are also similar to MonsterMMORPG,

Comment: Ryzen 3800X, dotnet core 3.1: 855, 1407, 950.

Comment: Windows, Ryzen 3600
.Net Core 3.1
    x64: 861, 961, 972;
    x86: 858, 962, 969;
.Net 5
    x64: 963, 1438, 959;
    x86: 958, 957, 1436;
.Net Framework 4.8
    x64: 2155, 967, 967;
    x86: 2154, 959, 959;
The results are an average of 5 runs.
Conclusion: Just use the `Math.Abs` function, unless you are on .Net Framework, in which case, use either of the others (I'll be using 2nd option)

Answer (score 7):

For what it's worth, absolute value of a 32-bit signed, 2's complement format int is usually implemented like this:

abs(x) = (x^(x>>31))-(x>>31)

Comment: Ah I doubt that. It's definitely not implemented that way in Java and since in .NET the abs() class throws an exception for -2^31, that trick also won't work.

Comment: You're certainly correct that .NET wouldn't implement it this way without any range or error checking, nor would any robust math library. But as with many library calls, if you know you don't need the range checking, you can possibly write something the executes faster.

Comment: your answer is the really correct one - how to write fast abs function. and it is the last one. I was looking for this one day and got lots of boll0cks from 'masters' or local univers aka hans passant and little jon... meritocrasy seems dont work either.

Comment: Patented by another master of the universe: http://www.patentgenius.com/patent/6073150.html

Comment: (x + (x >> 31)) ^ (x >> 31) works just as well and is not patented (even though the patent is probably not valid in court). Check the comments on this page: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs

Answer (score 3):

I just see if it is less than zero and multiply by -1

```
int d = (X < 0) ? (-X) : X;
```

Comment: This will be subtly different than `Math.Abs`. See: `int.MinValue`.

Comment: @Anthony Pegram - noted. I was trying for the Java implementation of Abs :)

Answer (score 2):

See http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs for how to compute absolute value without branching.

Whilst .Net supports inlining, I doubt that `Math.Abs()` would be considered a candidate for inlining by the compiler. Here's the implementation of the `int` overload, courtesy of Reflector.

```
public static int Abs(int value)
{
  if (value >= 0)
    {
      return value;
    }
  return AbsHelper(value);
}

private static int AbsHelper(int value)
{
  if (value == -2147483648)
  {
    throw new OverflowException(Environment.GetResourceString("Overflow_NegateTwosCompNum"));
  }
  return -value;
}
```

The overloads for other integral types are similar. The `float` and `double` overloads are external calls whilst the `decimal` overload uses its own implementation, which constructs a new instance. Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

C# does inline Math.Abs.  This works:

```
int x = 12;
int y = 17;
int z = Math.Abs(x - y);
Console.WriteLine(z); //outputs 5
```

Comment: It works, but it doesn't prove that the `Abs` call is inlined.

Answer (score 1):

C# does inline `Math.Abs()`, here is the C# and assembly code (generated using the online tool [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/)) of `Math.Abs`:

C#:

```
public int test(int n){
    return Math.Abs(n);
}
```

Assembly:

```
L0000: push ebp
L0001: mov ebp, esp
L0003: test edx, edx
L0005: jge L000d
L0007: neg edx
L0009: test edx, edx
L000b: jl L0011
L000d: mov eax, edx
L000f: pop ebp
L0010: ret
L0011: call System.Math.ThrowAbsOverflow()
L0016: int3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want real performance try this:

```
    int result = source & 0x7FFFFFFF;
```

It works by using bit AND operator ('&') and filters out the sign bit,
leaving the rest as is.
0x7FFFFFFF is the hex value of (1<<31), appropriate to use with int32 (default int)

For more info about bit operations go here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators

My times for this and other functions are as follow (ryzen 3900x):

```
    Math.Abs(i):        2224ms
    i>0?i:-1   :         958ms
    (i+(i>>31))^(i>>31): 953ms
    i&0x7FFFFFFF:        486ms
```

Comment: `-15 & 0x7FFFFFFF` is 2147483633, not the expected value = 15

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it is about the difference in for example a minimization problem you could use: a<b?b-a:a-b

Answer (score 0):

Calculating the abs of x mathematically is simple:

```
sqrt(x^2)
```